# Print an image in Javascript without opening a new window using windows.print()

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, printing, window

I have this image below:

```
 <img src="sample.png"></img>
```

Javascript code:

```
win = window.open(img.src,"_blank");
win.onload = function() {
    win.print();
}
```

I want to print the image without opening a window. How will I do that in javascript?

Comment: Here is a possible solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742144/how-to-print-a-image-file-in-printer

Comment: [CSS Print Stylesheet: hide everything except specific image, show that full-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416557/css-print-stylesheet-hide-everything-except-specific-image-show-that-full-page), [CSS - Print view - Hide all elements except one div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511745/css-print-view-hide-all-elements-except-one-div)